# useEffect does not refresh page content onClick

Tags: react-redux, react-hooks, react-router

Everything works, but not as it should. I scoured the internet, but did not find a solution of what could cause this issue. To my knowledge I did everything according to the "book".

I am building an e-commerce page. On the Admin page I can add/edit/remove product from the product list. When I remove a product, it is removed, but I only see this when I refresh the page, not when I click on the remove button. I. would like to see that the product is removed from the list when I delete the product.

I tried to use window.location.reload(true); in useEffect in the if statement. I checked the code multiple times with others working code. I tried different browsers. It didn't help. Maybe, I am overlooking something very simple.

My code is the following:

*Product List Screen*

```js
const productDelete = useSelector(state => state.productDelete);
const { loading: loadingDelete, error: errorDelete, success: successDelete } =  productDelete;

useEffect(() => {
        if (successDelete) {
          dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DELETE_RESET });
        }
        dispatch(listProducts());
}, [dispatch, successDelete]);

const deleteHandler = (product) => {
        if(window.confirm('Are you sure to delete?')){
            dispatch(deleteProduct(product._id));
        }
};

// some fancy code that maps over the product list and displays it along with the delete button

<button
 type="button"
 className="small"
 onClick={() => deleteHandler(product)}
 >
 Delete
</button>
```

*Delete Action Handler*

```js
export const deleteProduct = (productId) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DELETE_REQUEST, payload: productId });
    const {
      userSignin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();
    try {
      await axios.delete(`/api/products/${productId}`, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
      });
      dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DELETE_SUCCESS });
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message;
      dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DELETE_FAIL, payload: message });
    }
  };
```

*Action Reducer*

```js
export const productDeleteReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case PRODUCT_UPDATE_REQUEST:
            return { loading: true };
        case PRODUCT_DELETE_SUCCESS:
            return { loading: false, success: true };
        case PRODUCT_DELETE_FAIL:
            return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
        case PRODUCT_DELETE_RESET:
            return {};
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

*Delete router*

```js
  productRouter.delete(
    '/:id',
    isAuth,
    isAdmin,
    expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
      const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id);
      if (product) {
        const deleteProduct = await product.remove();
        res.send({ message: 'Product Deleted', product: deleteProduct });
      } else {
        res.status(404).send({ message: 'Product Not Found' });
      }
    })
  );

  export default productRouter;
```

*Store*

```
combine the reducer with the action handler in the store
```

All help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What actions are dispatched and what changes did they make to the state (redux devtools)? Is `listProducts` action dispatched?

Comment: Good question. In the redux dev tool, I see that, the state of listProducts is dispatched.

Answer (score 0):

After even longer searching in my code, I discovered that the answer was in the store file. I used autoimport, but instead of connecting the reducer with the right function ( `productDelete: productDeleteReducer`,) it was connected to another reducer. This of course caused this strange effect.